# How can I search manpages of a certain section range?

Tags: man, apropos

To give context, I want to do something like an this: `alias posix='man ?p'`, so that I could later type-in `posix time` and display `time(1p)`, `time(3p)`, etc..

Is this supported by `man` or will I have to hack something together with `apropos`?

Comment: like `man -a time` ?

Comment: that would get me all sections, I want within a set section range i.e. [1-3] or ?p or 1*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try either

```
MANSECT="1,2,3" man -a time
man -s 1,2,3 -a time
```

as per man itself

> -S list, -s list, --sections=list
> The  given  list  is a colon- or comma-separated list of sections, used to determine which manual sections to search and in
> what
> order. This option overrides the $MANSECT environment variable. (The -s spelling is for compatibility with System V.)

you will have to enumerate section, no range or wildcard.

Comment: thank you. This is good enough for my use-case, and it also suggests that any kind of wildcarding will have to be done separate of `man` itself.

Comment: for future reference and the sake of completion, to achieve the wildcard constraint with the help of `-s` (and `-a` from the comment on my question), one could do something like `man -s $(echo /usr/share/man/man* |grep -o '[0-9]p' |paste -sd',') -a time`